# Colocar un span debajo del select2

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, select2

Necesito colocar debajo de los input y select un span. Ahora bien, cuando trato de insertar mediante jQuery el mensaje debajo de los input funciona bien pero de los select el mensaje me sale arriba, esto únicamente sucede con los select de Select2.

[image: Select vs Select2]

Para añadir el mensaje utilizo la siguiente instruccion

```
$("#"+field_name").after('<span class="error text-danger">'+error+'</span>')
```

Comment: Si te fijas por la consola del navegador select2 modifica la estructura del select, revisa desde consola la estructura del select una vez cargada la pagina.

Comment: Por que no pones un span vacio debajo de cada input y luego le agregas el mensaje a ese span cuando sea necesario con Jquery: $("#span1").text(''Este campo es requerido")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando la estructura con la cual se convierte el select puro con el plugin de Select pude encontrar que cada select toma un id diferente y pude determinar que accediendo al id original no era posible cambiarlo y encontré la solucion con la siguiente instruccion.

```
$("#select2-"+field_name+"-container").after('<span class="error text-danger">'+error+'</span>')
```

Ahi podemos notar que el id se convierte con el prefijo **select2-** y el sufijo **-container**.

Comment: Excelente, a mi me pasaba igual con BootStrap-Select :)